# Capitalization rules of website copywriting in English

Tags: capitalization

There are some buttons, popups, and dialog boxes in my website and I want to use some uppercase letters in the copywriting.
Are there any rules while using uppercase letters in English.

For example, I have a button with text "Select a user", shall I use it as "Select a User" or "Select A User" ?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! There are all sorts of guidelines most of which are available online and can be reached by a quick google search, please **provide prior research** into your question's topic of it is out of this site's scope.

Comment: No, there are no "rules" for this, unless the company you work for has stated them.

Answer (score 1):

Go to any large web-site with a variety of features (Microsoft.com is a good example) and follow convention.

Basically, use sentence case everywhere you can, but title case named objects.